# How can I inject new Make targets in runtime after clonning a new repository?

Tags: makefile, gnu-make

My CI setup is the following: first I checkout a target repository with a Makefile with a couple of targets.

```
fooRepo
--- Makefile
...
```

and then I run `git clone ...barRepo.git` that contains a bunch of `*.mk` files with targets I want to *inject* such that I'll be able to run the targets from those `*.mk` files in CI pipeline right after I clone it.

My folder structure after cloning:

```
fooRepo
--- Makefile # contains init
--- barRepo
------- 123.mk # contains bar-init target
```

My expected CI pipeline:

```
- git clone fooRepo
- make init
- git clone barRepo
- # run something to enable bar-init target
- make bar-init
```

The approach I've tried was to created `includes.txt` file with

```
include ./barRepo/123.mk
```

and run

```
- git clone fooRepo
- make init
- git clone barRepo
- make -f includes.txt
- make bar-init
```

but even then I've got the error that `bar-init` target was not found (includes were performed successfully though?)

Comment: Every invocation of make has its own setup.  A second run doesn't "remember" the context of the first run.  Rather than two different invocations of make `make -f includes.txt` and `make bar-init`, you need to run one invocation: `make -f includes.txt bar-init`.

Comment: could you add it as an answer so I'll accept it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Every invocation of make has its own setup. A second run doesn't "remember" the context of the first run. Rather than two different invocations of make: `make -f includes.txt` followed by `make bar-init`, you need to run one invocation giving both the makefile to run and the target to build:

```
make -f includes.txt bar-init
```

Answer (score 0):

Your question is slightly unclear -- and you haven't shown us your makefile -- but I'll give it a try.

It looks as if your first step, `git clone fooRepo`, takes place before there is any makefile present, so that will have to be from the command line.

It is not clear what you want the `init` rule to do, nor which other rules depend on it, so I will leave it out for now.

The last three steps are the interesting part:

```
- git clone barRepo
- # run something to enable bar-init target
- make bar-init
```

The intuitive direct approach is to have a rule for `barRepo`, `include barRepo/123.mk` and a call to `bar-init`. The trouble is that Make will try to expand the `include` statement before executing any rule, which means before executing the `barRepo` rule, which means that `123.mk` will not yet exist, which means that the `include` statement will not work.

The solution is to run Make twice. More precisely, to have Make clone `barRepo`, then invoke *itself*, once `123.mk` is in place. This is a type of Recursive Make, which happens automatically when you provide a rule for the file to be included; if that file is absent or out of date, Make will attempt to build it, then restart itself.

```
-include barRepo/123.mk

bar-init:

barRepo:
    clone barRepo somehow

barRepo/123.mk: barRepo
    @:  # the rule must have a command; this command does nothing
```

Answer (score 0):

Just another way to inject your stuff in makefiles: The "-E <expr>" option allows Make to evaluate arbitrary expressions in Makefile syntax, eg an **include** statement, before the makefiles are read.